# How to search for Shiny Apps - Rstudio

Tags: shiny, rstudio

I'm entering the world of Shiny Rstudio now. So this is a beginner question

One question I came up with is: how do I search for the Shiny Apps available/created? Are all created Apps available? Is there any way that, once I create my app, I prevent it from being viewed? Or during the creation I "block it"?

From so much searching I found this link via Rstudio's website: http://www.showmeshiny.com/

Would this be the search platform for all apps made?

But in the case of http://www.showmeshiny.com/ it seems that it is necessary to send it via "Submit App".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your questions correctly but I might be able to give you some insights.

- **Are all created Apps available?**
  No, some shiny Apps are hosted on private servers or/and are embedded in password-protected websites or Wordpress-pages for example. If you dont have those access rights, then you cannot see those Apps.
- **How do I search for the Shiny Apps available/created?**
  There is no way of doing that, except on pages like [Showmeshiny](http://www.showmeshiny.com), the [RStudio Shiny Gallery](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/), this gallery of [recent Shiny-Apps](https://shinyapps-recent.appspot.com/recent.html) or pther similar pages. Those Apps are publicly available and you can submit your own App if you like sharing it. [Shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/) is a nice and easy way of deploying your App on a server with a few clicks. But you need at least the standard license to include authentication, otherwise they would be free and open for everyone.
- **Is there any way that, once I create my app, I prevent it from being
  viewed?**
  I am not quite sure, what you mean. If it should be blocked from being viewed at all, I dont see the reason of building a ShinyApp. If you just want to access it yourself, then there are ways of doing so. Either password-protect it where only you know the password or host it on a local server that only you can access.
- **Or during the creation I "block it"?**
  If you create it on your computer and run it, it will run on your computer and only be accessible to yourself, except you explicitly configure it otherwise. So there is no need of "blocking it".